# Java Plug-in is not supported by this browser on Apache Pivot web-site

Tags: java, browser, plugins, windows-10, apache-pivot

21st century.

Apache Pivot web site.

Latest release July 04, 2017, Pivot 2.0.5

Demos page: https://pivot.apache.org/demos/

Clicking any demo causes the following banner appear:

[image]

I tried in Chrome, Firefox and Opera.

If click `More info` it passes you to java download page: https://java.com/en/download/win10.jsp

How to fix?

I don't want to download and install latest JRE. I have JDK/JRE version installed and satisfied by it. I want it to run.

Comment: Very surprising they still have Java applet demos on their website.

Comment: How do you know they have Java applet demos?

Comment: I had to delete similar question about Why Verify Java Version not working in chrome

Comment: @user7294900 Because these are trade wars and solgiers are even on SO.

Comment: @Dims: *"How do you know they have Java applet demos?"* Because of the screenshot you've shown. The Java plug-in is for running Java applets in a browser.

Comment: @Dims You think if I un delete it now I'll get a good answer now?

Comment: @user7294900: No need, your answer is below.

Comment: @Dims But why Java uses Java applet to verify upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That message is telling you that the page is trying to run a Java applet (that's what the Java plug-in does).

If you want to run a Java applet, you'll have to use an obsolete (or minor brand) browser, which obviously one doesn't recommend.

Chrome and Firefox have both dropped support for the Java plug-in (and support for NPAPI plugins in general, although they've whitelisted Flash for a little while), and Edge never had it. Reasons for this vary depending on who you ask and when you ask them, but essentially A) The Java plug-in had a long history of security issues, B) Supporting the underlying NPAPI is a non-trivial technical debt that browser vendors no longer want to carry, C) Now that the web has matured a great deal, with native video, animation, etc., the need for NPAPI-style plugins is greatly reduced.

A **signed** Java applet will run in IE11 if you tell your Java installation to allow it (on the Java configuration applet's Security tab). I have no idea whether an unsigned one will. I hope not.

Otherwise, you can't run the Java applet. Because this is the 21st century. :-)

Comment: Does that mean one cannot even run the [Progress Applet Demo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/examples/dist/applet_AppletWithCustomProgressIndicator/AppletPage.html) from the [Oracle tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/customProgressIndicatorForApplet.html)? Don't have the JDK but that shouldn't be required to see it in action in Chrome.

Comment: @LaurieStearn: Yes. Applets are a dead technology.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the page Apache pivot uses Applet: `org.apache.pivot.wtk.BrowserApplicationContext$HostApplet` with signed jar as `pivot-core-2.0.5.signed.jar`.

It calls `runApplet` and fails on check:

```
if(document.readyState=="complete"){
  clearInterval(B);h()}},15);
  k("[runApplet()] Java Plug-in is not supported by this browser");return
}
```

The support of Applet technology is down due to security issues. see [great explanation](https://superuser.com/questions/1088584/why-is-the-java-plugin-jre-disabled-in-chrome) in superuser site.